# How would you structure the dates in this?

Tags: python, automation

Good morning,

Long story short, I had an issue last week, came up with a solution, but know it likely wasn't the best solution and wanted to reach out to the community and see if they had any better ideas. I'm also having issues keeping this concise, so I apologize for this.

After writing everything, I guess my question is, how would you have go about taking the calendars and make it, so Python clicked the correct date based on my search criteria.

I use a web program to run queries on a map. The steps I take are:

1. Draw a box over the area I want to search
2. Select the date I want to search from a calendar.
3. Run the query.  Once I hit run, the box is removed, and I have to redraw it.

Normally, this isn't an issue, because I only run one or two queries. However, this time I had to run over 60 queries, across three months. So, I decided to write I python script to do this for me.

In the past, I used Selenium and use it to interact with webpages.  However, I wanted to try something different, and I went with pyautogui to click on my screen.

To use pyautogui, I have to tell Python where to click.  Most of this is easy, because they are static buttons on the screen.  However, when it comes to the date, this is where things got tricky for me.

**The Challenge: Calendars**

I know the "easy button" is, just covert the date I wanted to search into something the program online will read and paste it into the date box.  Unfortunately, this calendar only lets you click the dates, no copy/pasting in dates.

Every month, the position of the dates change.  I took a screen clipping of three months of calendars (note, only one calendar appears on the screen at one time) [Image of Calendars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdtSv.png). So, if we were to imagine a (x,y) grid over the dates, the 1st of Aug is at (7, 6); 1st of Sept is (3,6); 1st of Oct is (5,6). If you were to look at October, where would you guess November started? It's not (1,6) but rather (1,5).  I'm getting ahead of myself, just trying to show this is the problem I was trying to solve, how to tell Python the 5th of A-Month was located at (X,Y) but the first of B-month was located at a different (X,Y).  The first thing I did was identify the x,y (in pixels) of each row and column.  So, the bottom most row was (x, 690), the next row was (x, 650) and so on.  I did the same for the columns until in excel I ended up with a sheet of grids. [Sheet of grids](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJAIZ.png)

I converted the sheet from the grid layout to a singular row. Then, looking back at the calendars, I noticed August started at the seventh item in the row. So, I created another excel labeled the B1 Aug-20 and in B2:B##, copied every item in singular row starting from the third item to the end. I also added row headers and did the same for September and October and in the end my sheet looked like: (note the | are not in the actual sheet, just here to illustrate new columns.)

Month |  Day Grid 1 |  Day Grid 2 | etc.,

Aug-20 | 1070, 510 |   880, 550 | etc.,

Sep-20 | 950, 510 |     980, 510 | etc.,

etc.

**Next the Code**

So, now that I know where the dates are I went into the code.  I had two csvs, one with the grid locations, and one with the dates I wanted to search. The search dates were formatted like so:

MMM-YY/D

Oct-20/6

Oct-20/7

Oct-20/14

Oct-20/16

My code ended up looking like

```
import csv
import collections
import pyautogui
import time

def rectdraw():
    pyautogui.click(1160,180) #Click draw rect box
    pyautogui.click(700,500)  #Click Upper Left
    pyautogui.click(1430,850) #Click Lower Right
    pyautogui.click(1430,850) #Click Lower Right

data_by_date = collections.defaultdict(list)
with open("MonthGrid.csv",encoding='utf-8') as inf:
    r = csv.DictReader(inf)
    for row in r:
        data_by_date[row["Month"]].append(row)

search = []
with open("Search.csv",encoding='utf-8') as file:
    for row in file:
        test1 = row.strip()
        test = test1.split("/")  
        search.append(test)        

for date in data_by_date:
    for searchdate in search:
        if searchdate[0] == date:
            for dates in data_by_date[date]:
                grids = dates[f'Day Grid {searchdate[1]}']
                grid = grids.split(",")
                rectdraw()
                time.sleep(.75)
                #A bunch of pyautogui.click() to clicking buttons on the page
                pyautogui.click(grid)
                pyautogui.click(grid)
```

I know this is long winded, and if you made it this far, I thank you.  If you have any questions, please ask.

Comment: Whoever produced that CSV forgot the Y2K bug - and the fact that both Lloyd's and Barclay's systems crashed in January 2020 because of such hacks. The standard for formatting dates is ISO8601 - `YYYY-MM-DD`

Comment: That would have been me, I guess I was too young for the y2k bug.  Let's just say somewhere along the way the dates were saved and 20-Aug, became 20 Aug 2022 in the CSV and I just used a custom format (DD-MMM). I admit, I was lazy, and didn't feel like changing the dates. This does cause some issues in the code, because the date 20-Aug is being compared against Aug-20, and they aren't the same, making me manually have to go and change it.  Good Catch.